# convert an array of objects (created from OpenStruct) into an array of values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I am learning ruby and I am playing with a sample data. I converted following hash into an array of objects as follows.

```
class Openstruct
  require 'JSON'
  require 'ostruct'

  HASH = {
    items: [
      {
        health: [
          {
            goal: [
              {
                activity: [
                  {
                    id: "1A"
                  },
                  {
                    id: "2A"
                  }
                ],
                id: "GA"
              }
            ],
            activity: [
              {
                id: "1B"
              },
              {
                id: "2B"
              }
            ],
            id: "GB"
          }
        ],
        goal: [
          {
            activity: [
              {
                id: "1C"
              },
              {
                id: "2C"
              },
            ],
            id: "3c"
          }
        ],
        createdAt: "2018-01-01",
        updatedAt: "2018-01-01",
        id: "DA"
      }
    ],
  }

  def self.all
    json = HASH.to_json
    JSON.parse(json, object_class: OpenStruct)
  end

end
```

Above returns me following result

```
#<OpenStruct items=
  [#<OpenStruct health=
      [#<OpenStruct goal=
        [#<OpenStruct activity=
          [#<OpenStruct id="1A">, #<OpenStruct id="2A">], id="GA">], 
          activity=[#<OpenStruct id="1B">, #<OpenStruct id="2B">], id="GB">], 
          goal=[#<OpenStruct activity=[#<OpenStruct id="1C">, #<OpenStruct id="2C">], id="3c">], 
          createdAt="2018-01-01", 
          updatedAt="2018-01-01", 
          id="DA">]>
```

However, i want to convert the array of object having id's into array of values of ids. e.g `[#<OpenStruct id="1A">, #<OpenStruct id="2A">]` --> ["1A", "2A"]. so i want the final result as follows:

```
#<OpenStruct items=
  [#<OpenStruct health=
      [#<OpenStruct goal=
        [#<OpenStruct activity=
          ["1A","2A"], id="GA">], 
          activity=["1B", 2B"], id="GB">], 
          goal=[#<OpenStruct activity=["1C","2C"], id="3c">], 
          createdAt="2018-01-01", 
          updatedAt="2018-01-01", 
          id="DA">]>
```

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: That's the tallest hash I've seen in a long time. In real life consider doing some shortening such as making the following one line:  `{ activity: [{ id: "1A" }, { id: "2A" }], id: "GA" }` (or even `goal: [{ activity: [{ id: "1A" }, { id: "2A" }], id: "GA" }],`). Isn't that just as clear? It's helpful to be able to view an entire object without having to scroll vertically (and even more so, horizontally). Of course, if one were paid by the line of code..

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check the child node recursively until you find the `OpenStruct` with only `:id` element. Following is the working code for your sample data.

```
def self.convert_struct_id(os)
  # Get possible attributes of any open_struct
  attributes = os.to_h.keys

  # Only get id_value if :id is the only attribute of open_struct
  if attributes.length == 1 && attributes.first == :id
    id_value = os.send(:id)
    return id_value
  end

  # Iterate through attributes
  attributes.each do |attr|
    # Get child elements
    data = os.send(attr)
    case data
    when OpenStruct
      convert_struct_id(data)
    when Array
      # Recursively process for child node
      data.map! { |d| convert_struct_id(d) }
    end
  end
  return os
end
```

Your `self.all` method will look like this

```
def self.all
  json = HASH.to_json
  os = JSON.parse(json, object_class: OpenStruct)
  res = convert_struct_id(os)
end
```

Result:

```
=> #<OpenStruct items=[#<OpenStruct health=[#<OpenStruct goal=[#<OpenStruct activity=["1A", "2A"], id="GA">], activity=["1B", "2B"], id="GB">], goal=[#<OpenStruct activity=["1C", "2C"], id="3c">], createdAt="2018-01-01", updatedAt="2018-01-01", id="DA">]>
```